# Query throwing operator and should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Im working on this query and wanted to bring the metric to a date level, but when I ended up adding the filed to the metric subquery it threw me this error. I looked around a bit to see what can be done but still not sure how to resolve it :/

```
  SELECT MAX(end_d)offer_end_date,
  IF(o.end_d>=[?FD58AFE1416C9D8D7313EA9425FA7CF6[?,1,0) active_of,
  offer_budget,
      (SELECT clip_date, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0) 
       FROM data_mining.clip_summary stb 
       WHERE stb.offer_id=o.oid AND clip_date>=[..] 
           AND clip_date>=SUBDATE(o.st_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
           AND clip_date<=ADDDATE(o.end_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
           AND clip_date<=[..]
           AND is_handraiser<>1 group by clip_date
    ) AS clips_cur
FROM rp.mstr_all_offer_sum o 
JOIN data_mining.clip_summary s ON s.offer_id=o.oid
JOIN mstr_all_clip_red_sum d ON d.offer_id = o.oid
WHERE target_type<>'targeted' 
      AND st_d<=ADDDATE([...]?  ,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      AND end_d>=SUBDATE([...]?, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
       AND clip_date BETWEEN[...]? AND [...]?
```

I tried adding 'clip_date' to the query but no luck. Any idea how can rework this?

Comment: Some more information would help out a lot. 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @alexherm operator and should contain 1 column(s) is the error

Answer (score 0):

It's this segment beginning on the fourth line:

```
 (SELECT clip_date, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0)
```

This is in the `SELECT` clause, and in the `SELECT` clause nested subquery can only return **one column**. However, the results from thsi subquery have *two columns*.

To fix this, you'll either need to run the subquery twice — once for each field — or find a way to work the source data into the JOINs. The other way is rewrite this using [`LATERAL JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) for the subquery.

```
SELECT MAX(end_d)offer_end_date,
   IF(o.end_d>=[?FD58AFE1416C9D8D7313EA9425FA7CF6[?,1,0) active_of,
   offer_budget, lj.clip_date, lj.clips_cur
FROM rp.mstr_all_offer_sum o 
JOIN data_mining.clip_summary s ON s.offer_id=o.oid
JOIN mstr_all_clip_red_sum d ON d.offer_id = o.oid
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
       SELECT clip_date, IFNULL(SUM(current_clip_count),0) as clips_cur
       FROM data_mining.clip_summary stb 
       WHERE stb.offer_id=o.oid AND clip_date>=[..] 
           AND clip_date>=SUBDATE(o.st_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
           AND clip_date<=ADDDATE(o.end_d, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
           AND clip_date<=[..]
           AND is_handraiser<>1 
       GROUP BY clip_date
) lj
WHERE target_type<>'targeted' 
      AND st_d<=ADDDATE([...]?  ,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      AND end_d>=SUBDATE([...]?, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
       AND clip_date BETWEEN[...]? AND [...]?
```

I suspect, though, the `clips_cur` field could be handled better using a [windowing function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).

Comment: Hmm, I see. Making this work with the join doesnt seem possible, I might either try it with a case statement or maybe a new table with the needed levels.

Comment: @dummyboi I made a mistake with the original answer. MySql 8.0.14 does support lateral join, so you should be able to move the subquery to the JOINs without changing too much.

Comment: Oh nice, I will take a look into it. Thanks!